# ASP.NET Web API - OWIN - TokenEndPointPath not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have the following code in my startup.cs. Setting up the TokenEndpointPath works perfectly in IIS Express and when the Web API project is deployed to the root of a website in IIS. However, if I host in a nested application (i.e. an application within a website) in IIS calls to the token endpoint result in a 404. Is there a way to base the TokenEndpointPath off of the actual IIS structure instead of the root, as it does here? Right now:

**This Works**

http://server:80/api/token

**This does not**

http://server:80/app/api/token

```
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(newOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = newPathString("/api/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(oauthTokenTimeoutInMinutes), 

        Provider = new Provider.ActiveDirectoryAuthorizationServerProvider()
    });
```

Comment: I have tested your issue in my localhost IIS, it responses 500 with details `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.`

Comment: @BNK I appreciate your response. However, yours is a SQL issue which suggests that the sample project your using has a database related issue. I think this is unrelated to my issue above.

Comment: I mean that I try `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Token"),` then I works in IISExpress, however not working in local IIS (web published), however, response code is 500, not 404 (database is attached file in App_Data folder)

Comment: @JP, do you have a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @JP. Any solution yet to this one?

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxIly3fyoM0 . It actually tells about a package that should be there to make owin endpoints work. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

As commented, I have tested your issue by setting `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Token")`. At first, my `connectionString` looks like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApi-20150818041808.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApi-20150818041808;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
  </connectionStrings>
```

After publishing the project to Local IIS (7.5), getting 500 error response when sending POST request to

> http://localhost/webapi/api/token

Then I updated `connectionString` like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.247;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

It works like the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone is still looking for the solution, this may help:
[image]

Ensure you have HTTPS or set this to "true".