# OAuth Calling TokenEndpointPath results in The controller for path was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt, access-token

Followed [this](http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/03/asp-net-identity-2-accounts-confirmation-password-user-policy-configuration/) manual and built token authentication. It works perfectly in the debug mode but in the release mode a call to the TokenEndpointPath results in

> The controller for path '/bps/oauth/token' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.

The URI has the /bps/ part because of the WebBaseUri in the Web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="WebBaseUrl" value="/bps/" />
<add key="WebApiBaseUrl" value="/api/" />
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
<add key="LoginErrorMessage" value="Login or email is wrong" />
```

The Startup class is following:

```
    public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<OwinExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();

        var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WindsorInstaller());
        container.Register(Component.For<IAppBuilder>().Instance(app));
        var httpDependencyResolver = new WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(container);

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorControllerActivator(container));


        ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app, container);

        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app, IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = container.Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>(),
            AccessTokenFormat = container.Resolve<CustomJwtFormat>(),
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"]);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of the IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider that's being resolved for the **Provider** property:

```
    public class OAuthService : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly IApplicationUserService _userService;
    private readonly ICredentialsValidatior _credentialsValidatior;

    public OAuthService(IApplicationUserService userService, ICredentialsValidatior credentialsValidatior)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
        _credentialsValidatior = credentialsValidatior;
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
        if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        /* Some user validation logick */

        var user = await _userService.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);

        context.Validated(ticket);
    }

    private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        const string authenticationType = "JWT";
        var userIdentity = await _userService.CreateIdentityAsync(user, authenticationType);

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Class that's being resolved for the **AccessTokenFormat** property:

```
    public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    private readonly string _issuer;

    public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
    {
        _issuer = issuer;
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceId"];

        string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceSecret"];

        var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

        var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

        var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

        var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

        return jwt;
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This code is run on my local machine and works fine in the Debug and Release mode.

The problem occurs when this code is published to the development server in debug mode.

I found out that switching the **AllowInsecureHttp** property to false on the local machine leads to this error but the version on the dev server is exactly the same. I checked the IL code and the **AllowInsecureHttp** property there is set to 1.

**UPDATE**

I tried to add the /bps/ part to the TokenEndpointPath but it didn't help.

For unknown reason now it doesn't work even locally.
I found out that project's settings are such 
[image]

I tried to find these settings on the dev server, unfortunately, because of the lack of my knowledge about IIS, I didn't find anything.

I also tried to check the OWIN pipeline and found out that URL that's being passed through the pipeline is the same that's configured in the Startup.cs.

[image]

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853803/asp-net-web-api-owin-tokenendpointpath-not-working-in-iis) question on the StackOverflow.

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue. 1) what is `/bps` in relation to url of hosted application. 2) in what order was `ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration` method called during startup. 3) is this release mode on the same machine or on a separate server? 4) include any other contextual information that may be missing by providing a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Nkosi Hope that my edited question has more precise information.

Comment: those first two app setting look custom and not framework related. Change `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),` to `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/bps/oauth/token"),` and see if it works. looks like it works on local machine by chance because it so happens the folders match up but when on dev that folder structure does not match so it fails

Comment: Thanks, @Nkosi , for an option. Unfortunately it didn't succeed. I assume that the reason is truly in the settings of the IIS and OWIN. Maby ther's a special way to host OWIN applications in the IIS?

Comment: i also facing same issue, any solution pls...

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you probably want to change `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorControllerActivator(container));
` to `config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorControllerActivator(container));
` in your startup